# Transforming a set-cookie Session Cookie header in Apache after the content is generated in Java

Tags: java, apache, session, cookies

How can I have an apache config that takes an original web-page generated by a java application server and transforms the set-cookie session header to have an extra flag.

i.e.

**From**

```
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=f232xxx; path=/moedev-wss; secure
```

**To**

```
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=f232xxx; path=/moedev-wss; secure; httponly
```

Unfortunately the java code I have cannot easily be updated, but if I can change the header in Apache, my problems are solved.

Note I have investigated the following Modules:

- mod_headers: cannot search content generated by other generators.
- mod_rewrite: doesn't edit content that isn't proxied.
- mod_proxy: doesn't edit content that isn't proxied.

Why would I want to do this?, in short: security issues see [OWASP on the subject](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer found in the MOD_SECURITY framework**

After I left the question above, I thought about what apache modules could help.

Then I searched mod_security for this information.

I found Ryan Barnett's excellent article and rule-set.

[Helping Protect Cookies with HTTPOnly Flag](http://blog.modsecurity.org/2008/12/helping-protect-cookies-with-httponly-flag.html)

Rule-set from Link above:

```
# Identifies SessiondIDs without HTTPOnly flag and sets the "http_cookie" ENV
# Token for Apache to read
SecRule RESPONSE_HEADERS:/Set-Cookie2?/ "!(?i:\;? ?httponly;?)" "chain,phase:3,t:none,pass,nolog"
  SecRule MATCHED_VAR "(?i:(j?sessionid|(php)?sessid|(asp|jserv|jw)?session[-_]?(id)?|cf(id|token)|sid))" "t:none,setenv:http_cookie=%{matched_var}"

# Now we use the Apache Header directive to set the new data

Header set Set-Cookie "%{http_cookie}e; HTTPOnly" env=http_cookie
```

My thanks to Ryan Barnett, and mod_security in general.

Now I will go ahead and test this solution in my environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this ruleset (and commands) seem to be incompatible with Oracle Application Server 10G R2, 10.1.2.